# TeeChart v8: How to change fonts in runtime?

Tags: c++, fonts, activex, teechart

Goal:

I want to change fonts in runtime. For example change font of legend text, titles, axis lables and so on.

Problem:

I can't find any function to change fonts by passing CFont object. I used function SetFont ( m_chartObj.SetFont( pFont ) ) but it doesn't change anything. I think I should change font separately for legend, axis and other objects, but I can't find such functions.

Question:

Does someone know such functions in order to change fonts during runtime, not in editor?

Answer (score 1):

As you've probably found, the editor includes the option to change all the fonts at once:

[image]

However, there isn't a function to do the same at runtime, so you should change the properties of all the fonts you want to change manually.
Ie, in VB6:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()            
  TChart1.AddSeries scBar
  TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues 8

  ChangeFont TChart1.Axis.Left.Labels.Font
  ChangeFont TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Labels.Font
  ChangeFont TChart1.Header.Font
  ChangeFont TChart1.Legend.Font
  ChangeFont TChart1.Series(0).Marks.Font
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeFont(fnt As IChartFont)
  fnt.Bold = True
  fnt.Name = "Arial"
  fnt.Size = 10
End Sub
```